# How to assign values to objects in numpy-array using vectorize

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a beginner with python and I wrote this code to create a bidimensional numpy-array of objects to simulate a physical lattice.

```
    import numpy as np  

    class Site:
       def __init__(self, label, status):
          self.l = label
          self.s = status

     vSite = np.vectorize(Site(0,2), otypes=[object])
     init_array = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
     lattice = np.empty((5,5), dtype=object)
     lattice[:,:] = vSite(init_array)
```

but I have errors in output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0c0dfed8eab8> in <module>()
      9 init_array = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
     10 lattice = np.empty((5,5), dtype=object)
---> 11 lattice[:,:] = vSite(init_array)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2753             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   2754 
-> 2755         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   2756 
   2757     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2823             res = func()
   2824         else:
-> 2825             ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
   2826 
   2827             # Convert args to object arrays first

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   2770                 ufunc = self._ufunc
   2771             else:
-> 2772                 ufunc = self._ufunc = frompyfunc(func, len(args), nout)
   2773         else:
   2774             # Get number of outputs and output types by calling the function on

TypeError: function must be callable
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: You should probably just use `list` objects instead of `numpy`

Answer (score 1):

The `np.vectorize()` function must take a function as first argument, not a common variable. The function it is called upon will then be able to be called on a numpy array to apply it on every element of the array.

If you want to initialize a 3D numpy array, you should use the `np.empty(dim)` function as follow :

```
a=np.empty((n,m,l), dtype=object)
```

This array will have n * m * l values.
You can then iterate through the matrix with a loop to fill it :

```
for i in np.ndindex(a.shape):
    a[i] = Site(1,1)
```

Comment: But there is already an initialization with np.empty. Could you answer with a runnable example?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `np.frompyfunc` is the best tool for creating arrays of custom classes.  Your use of `np.vectorize` also works, since you specify the `otypes`, but `frompyfunc` already returns objects, and is a bit more direct and faster.

```
In [667]: class Site: 
     ...:        def __init__(self, label, status): 
     ...:           self.l = label 
     ...:           self.s = status 
     ...:        def __repr__(self):   # to improve display
     ...:            return f'Site({self.l},{self.s})' 
     ...:                                                                            
In [668]: f = np.frompyfunc(Site, 2,1)                                               
In [669]: f(np.zeros((2,3),int), np.ones((2,3),int)*2)                               
Out[669]: 
array([[Site(0,2), Site(0,2), Site(0,2)],
       [Site(0,2), Site(0,2), Site(0,2)]], dtype=object)
In [670]: f(np.arange(3),np.array(['a','b','c']))                                    
Out[670]: array([Site(0,a), Site(1,b), Site(2,c)], dtype=object)
```

I should warn you though that accessing those `Site` objects will also require the use of `frompyfunc`.  Arrays of objects do not take full advantage of `numpy` computational speed. `numpy` computation is fastest when working with numbers, not objects.